# Cannot install various applications due to .NET framework wrongly reported missing

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

The applications in question are:

- nUnit 2.6.1: "NUnit requires .NET 2.0, .NET, 4.0 or Mono to be installed as a prerequisite."
- PowerCommands for VS2008: "Please install .NET framework 3.5"

The versions of .NET I currently have on my system are:

- 3.5.1 (Windows 7 feature)
- Compact framework 2.0 SP2
- Compact framework 3.5
- Framework 4 client/extended

I've tried removing all frameworks and Visual Studio 2008  (via the "Uninstall or change a program" tool) and reinstalling them (first via Windows Update, then installing VS2008).  However, I get the same errors.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

(Windows 7 SP1)

Comment: Tried installing 2.0, but complains that I have a higher version (3.5)

Answer (score 4):

I too faced same problem,  to solve what I did is

Go to RUN -> CMD  -> Open commandPrompt with 'Run As Administrator'
change the directory path to your Nunit location
ex: >D:\softwares
now type the Nuint complete name with extensions
ex: D:\softwares> NUnit-2.6.3.msi , hit ENTER

You will be prompted with similar NUnit Installation window.click Next, Next...
Nunit installed successfully ...

*NOTE:*
This will work only if you are already installed with required .NET frameworks like ( .NET 2.0, .NET, 4.0 or Mono)

Comment: this works for `nunit.3.2.0.msi` too

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error installing NUnit 2.6.0 on Windows 7, despite the fact that I have all the .NET Framework versions up to 4.0 installed (1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0).

I got past the error message by running the installer with administrator privileges (Right click > Run as admin).

Comment: Used this post to install as admin: http://www.howtogeek.com/178826/how-to-force-an-msi-package-to-install-using-administrator-mode/

Answer (score 0):

I rather suggest you properly run a windows update to fix the problem. Windows 7 are the best reliable built-in .NET framework 3.5 or even higher. So, try updating your system (if the update really works) and you will see it working.